# Users' list view based on current logged in user taxonomy field value

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, users

I'm on drupal 7, with views 3.5.

I have added to the user profile, a taxonomy field.

I want to create a view, which will get the users which that taxonomy field has the same value with the current logged in user taxonomy field value.

Is it possible?

Comment: use contextual filters.

Comment: Well this is where I'm trying to get this working. But on "provide default value" there is no option to get the current users taxonomy field. Only uid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your taxonomy field is labelled User Tag and has a machine name field_user_tag.

1. Create a view that lists users
2. Add a contextual filter for `User:
   User tag (field_user_tag)`
3. Under **WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT IN
   THE URL** Select 'Provide a Default Value' and then Select 'PHP
   Code'
4. Insert the following snippet:

   ```
   global $user;
   $term= user_load($user->uid)->field_user_tag;
   return $term['und'][0]['tid'];
   ```

The PHP code grabs the current user. In this context the current user object doesn't have any additional fields loaded. So we need the `user_load` function to get those. The we need to extract the taxonomy id from the relevant array.

This approach works, but may not be the best or most efficient.

Comment: Please what of if the field is a 'Select list field' created uding "Profile 2 module" ?

Comment: Perhaps this solution works in some use cases, it didn't in mine even though it seemed to match exactly. I'm not downvoting or saying this isn't a valid solution, but if this doesn't help you, try [this solution](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171842/a-view-that-displays-content-with-taxonomy-term-of-current-user).